# Error when returning to a page and adding controls in code behind

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7, xaml

In my Windows Phone app (VB/XAML) I am having trouble creating XAML controls in code behind *when returning to a page*.

Basically what my page is trying to do when it crashes is create some controls based on the datacontext. The controls are created correctly at first, then when the page is left and returned to the controls will no longer create (regardless of whether the same data object is being used to populate the page). This is the line that crashes:

```
ItemStack1.Children.Add(AnswerPanel1)
```

I just get a generic "System.InvalidOperationException" error.

I have checked that up to that point everything is as I expect - the data object is populated correctly regardless of how the page is navigated to. I've also attempted to narrow the issue by trying to remove the AnswerPanel1 item before trying to add it. I suspect the app is 'remembering' the page from when it was last opened and this is causing me to 'double up' something.

If I use "Try...Catch" around this line the control is missing from the page (which to me implies that the control doesn't exist, which I thought was the reason (re)creating it was failing the 2nd time.

I navigate to the page with this:

```
NavigationService.Navigate("/CasebookSelectCasePage.xaml", sItem)
```

...which uses a little 'helper' class to pass the sItem object, but within the class it navigates normally, like this:

```
 service.Navigate(New Uri(page, UriKind.Relative))
```

I think I'm missing something fundamental or obvious...do I need to 'flush' the page out of memory when navigating backwards to the front page?

Comment: More info from troubleshooting: it seems that it's only when repopulating the page with the same object it has previously had that the error occurs - e.g. send object1 the first time and it works perfectly...send object2 and it works properly...but if I try to send either object1 or object2 a second time (back to previous page then tap on the item again to launch the new page) I get the error.On the device the first part of the error message is "Element is already the child of another element".

Comment: I think I've found the problem but not the answer...it's the object that I'm passing to the new page that's the problem. I think I need to create a NEW copy before passing it through (I can make it work by hardcoding the object I pass, but I don't know how to create a new object of the correct type to pass on instead of passing the same copy as before. e.g. the object tapped is "Object1", instead of passing Object1 I want to pass a New Object1 (which inherits from Object, but I don't know at runtime if I need Object1 or Object2, etc - but they are all inherited from Object).

Comment: So, you're at the page A. Then you go to page B. Then you navigate back to page A and it crashes? Why are you repopulating controls again? Have you tried without it? The page A should be cached. Or before adding the new items to ItemStack, try clearing it first.

Comment: It fails when I go back to Page B: Page A - click an item, item is sent to Page B and everything is fine. Go back to Page A, click on the same item again, and Page B fails to load at the point where it's creating usercontrols based on the data in the object being passed. The issue goes away if I send a new copy of my object instead of the same copy that is in Page A - but I don't know how to do this without hardcoding it. I need to pass an object of type Object_Subtype1. How can I create a new copy of an object of the same type and subtype (inheritance) as the one clicked?

Comment: The AnswerPanel is already added to the stackpanel. Have you tried calling ItemStack1.Children.Clear() when navigating from the page B (to clear the stack and make the AnswerPanel without a parent) or as the first step when navigating to page B, again to do the same thing?

Comment: I've worked around the problem rather than solving it. Instead of creating my controls within my objects, I am now storing a "key" that represents the type of control needed, and the control is created directly on the page by the page's code behind (whereas before my objects were creating the controls and the page taking them and adding them to the layout). I don't understand what was happening before, but I suspect that I was trying to create the items a 2nd time somehow.

Comment: @ igrali, Yes, I tried clearing the parent of its items with no success. I now think I was creating the controls twice rather than trying to populate them on the page twice, but with XAML errors it's often hard to track down the cause. My workaround works, so it will do...it's just less elegant than I'd like. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hmm...I tried ItemSTack1.Children.Clear just before adding the controls(in OnNavigatedTo()). I will have a look at doing it when page B is left and see how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

When do you try to create your controls exactly? Are you creating them in OnNavigatedTo() or in Page_Loaded() ? It's not the same in which you try to create your objects.

Comment: My controls are created in the object that is sent to the page (i.e. before the page exists), and then I add them to the page layout (Grid1.Children.Add method) in the OnNavigatedTo(). In my workaround I both create and place the controls in the OnNAvigatedTo() and it functions as expected. The drawback is that when I want to add new control types to my app I will have to hard code the logic in the page rather than in the objects themselves.

Comment: I have the functionality I want, so in that sense it's working. But I redesigned how the app works because I couldn't get it to work correctly in the way I was trying.